# Can Algernon’s Revolver be obtained in the epilogue?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

The side quest [Duchesses and Other Animals](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Duchesses_and_other_Animals) involves a very tedious grind and I am just a few story missions away from completing Arthur’s portion of the game. I have been searching days for the first part alone for the Lady of the Night Orchids and am ready for a story mission break but still want all of the weapons.

Can this side quest be continued as John or do I have to suck it up and continue the grind as Arthur?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Anthony! I've fixed the typo in your post. You can do that yourself in the future by using the 'edit' button right below your question.

Comment: Yep, I had barely started that quest as Arthur, but finished the rest of the grind in the epilogue and got the revolver.  I have absolutely zero proof of this that could be shared here, hence just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Can you please  edit the title of this post so it doesn't have a spoiler about the ending of the game?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

There's a wide range of cigarette cards, animals, plants, and other items that exist in New Austin, which is opened up in the epilogue.

It does seem rather pointless that Arthur would be introduced to the cigarette card grind early in Chapter 2 if there was no way that the task could be completed.

If in doubt, just create a manual save slot to preserve where you are in Chapter 6 so that you're able to get back to it if required.